# Python/Kivy : not working properly vertical scrollbar in dynamic row

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, kivy, kivy-language

I have two files `demo.py` and `demo.kv`
I have a button `+Add More` which add row dynamic.I am trying to add vertical scrollbar in dynamic row using `ScrollView:`.But its not working properly.
its mean when i add row in scrollview that row having extra space in scrollview i want add rows without any spacing.

```
ScrollView:
            BoxLayout:
                orientation: "horizontal"
                size_hint_y: None
                height: 500

                Rows:
                    id: rows
```

## demo.py

```
import kivy
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import StringProperty

Window.clearcolor = (0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1)
Window.size = (500, 400)

class user(Screen):

    def add_more(self):
        self.ids.rows.add_row()


class Row(BoxLayout):
    button_text = StringProperty("")


class Rows(BoxLayout):
    orientation = "vertical"
    row_count = 0

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Rows, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.add_row()

    def add_row(self):
        self.row_count += 1
        self.add_widget(Row(button_text=str(self.row_count)))


class Test(App):

    def build(self):
        self.root = Builder.load_file('demo.kv')
        return self.root


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Test().run()
```

## demo.kv

```
<Button@Button>:
    font_size: 15
    font_name: 'Verdana'

<Label@Label>:
    font_size: 15
    font_name: 'Verdana'

<TextInput@TextInput>:
    font_size: 15
    font_name: 'Verdana'
    padding_y: 3


<Row>:
    GridLayout:
        cols: 2
        row_force_default: True
        row_default_height: 40

        Button:
            text: root.button_text
            size_hint_x: None
            top: 200

        Button:
            text: 'World 1'
            width: 300


user:

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        padding : 20, 5


        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "horizontal"
            #padding : 10, 10
            spacing: 10, 10
            size: 450, 40
            size_hint: None, None

            Label:
                size_hint_x: .2
                text: "Test 1"
                text_size: self.size
                valign: 'bottom'
                halign: 'center'

            Label:
                size_hint_x: .8
                text: "Test 2"
                text_size: self.size
                valign: 'bottom'
                halign: 'center'


        ScrollView:
            BoxLayout:
                orientation: "horizontal"
                size_hint_y: None
                height: 500

                Rows:
                    id: rows


        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "horizontal"
            size_hint_x: .2
            size_hint_y: .2

            Button:
                text: "+Add More"
                on_press: root.add_more()


        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "horizontal"
            padding : 10, 5
            spacing: 10, 10
            size_hint: .5, .35
            pos_hint: {'x': .25, 'y':.25}

            Button:
                text: 'Ok'

            Button:
                text: 'Cancel'
```

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you want to happen? It seems to work for me.

Comment: @JohnAnderson hello, its mean when i add row in scrollview that row having extra space in scrollview i want add rows in gridlist without any spacing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood what you want, you have too many nested `Layouts`, that are unnecessary. `Rows` should be the main layout of your `ScrollView`.

On the other hand, `Rows` should always have the lowest possible height to contain their widgets (`minimun_height` property), not a fixed size.

**Demo.py:**

```
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import StringProperty

Window.clearcolor = (0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1)
Window.size = (500, 400)

class User(Screen):

    def add_more(self):
        self.ids.rows.add_row()


class Row(BoxLayout):
    button_text = StringProperty("")


class Rows(BoxLayout):
    row_count = 0

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Rows, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.add_row()

    def add_row(self):
        self.row_count += 1
        self.add_widget(Row(button_text=str(self.row_count)))


class Test(App):

    def build(self):
        self.root = Builder.load_file('Demo.kv')
        return self.root


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Test().run()
```

**Demo.kv:**

```
<Button@Button>:
    font_size: 15
    font_name: 'Verdana'

<Label@Label>:
    font_size: 15
    font_name: 'Verdana'

<TextInput@TextInput>:
    font_size: 15
    font_name: 'Verdana'
    padding_y: 3


<Row>:
    size_hint_y: None
    height: self.minimum_height
    height: 40

    Button:
        text: root.button_text
        size_hint_x: None
        top: 200

    Button:
        text: 'World 1'
        width: 300

<Rows>:
    size_hint_y: None
    height: self.minimum_height
    orientation: "vertical"

User:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        padding : 20, 5


        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "horizontal"
            #padding : 10, 10
            spacing: 10, 10
            size: 450, 40
            size_hint: None, None

            Label:
                size_hint_x: .2
                text: "Test 1"
                text_size: self.size
                valign: 'bottom'
                halign: 'center'

            Label:
                size_hint_x: .8
                text: "Test 2"
                text_size: self.size
                valign: 'bottom'
                halign: 'center'


        ScrollView:
            Rows:
                id: rows


        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "horizontal"
            size_hint_x: .2
            size_hint_y: .2

            Button:
                text: "+Add More"
                on_press: root.add_more()


        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "horizontal"
            padding : 10, 5
            spacing: 10, 10
            size_hint: .5, .35
            pos_hint: {'x': .25, 'y':.25}

            Button:
                text: 'Ok'

            Button:
                text: 'Cancel'
```

[image]